# Blackberry Eclipse Plugin for Android Error

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry, ssh-keys, blackberry-android

I am trying to add Blackberry Eclipse Plugin for the purpose of porting an Android app.

But after installing plugin, when I click **Blackberry Tools SDK** as said in the documentation, it gives me the error:

> The currently displayed page contains invalid values.

[image]

And I can not do anything.  Also what is the public ssh key that needs to be defined?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The *"Target"* in this case is the device you want to load your software onto ... the BlackBerry mobile device.

This is allowing you to setup [SSH public key authentication](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.55/htmldoc/Chapter8.html) to let Eclipse transfer code to the device.

There's a few steps involved.  Basically, you'll install something like [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html) on your development machine, and use `puttygen` to create a public/private key pair.  Then, you use `blackberry-connect` to transfer the public key to your device.  After that, Eclipse will be able to use this keypair for ssh'ing into the device, without prompting you for username and password every time (you basically are giving your public key to the BlackBerry so it knows to recognize that key as an authorized key for logins).

After creating the keys and transferring the public key, the **SSH Key Path** field you show in your screenshot should be the Windows path to the *private* key you just generated.

[Here are the instructions on BlackBerry.com](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/tkb/articleprintpage/tkb-id/Testing_and_Deployment_of_Applications@tkb/article-id/168)

### Other Tutorials

[Related instructions for Playbook](http://blog.skufel.net/2012/07/how-to-access-blackberry-playbook-via-ssh/)

[Related instructions for Z10 - skip to #2](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2013/07/ssh-to-the-blackberry-z10-guide/#.Ue5EfVOrvQw)